# Select constant based on the generic type in rust function

Tags: generics, rust

Is there any way to select the value of a constant depending on the generic type?

For example, something like (not valid Rust code):

```
fn foo<T>() {
    let b = match T {
        u32 => 0x01234567u32,
        u64 => 0x0123456789abcdefu64,
        _ => panic!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo::<u32>();
    foo::<u64>();
}
```

This function would be only designed to operate with `u16`, `u32` and `u64` types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [associated constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants) of a trait:

```
trait MyTrait {
    const SOME_CONST: Self;
}

impl MyTrait for u32 {
    const SOME_CONST: Self = 0x01234567u32;
}

impl MyTrait for u64 {
    const SOME_CONST: Self = 0x0123456789abcdefu64;
}

fn foo<T>() where T: MyTrait {
    let _b: T = T::SOME_CONST;
}

fn main() {
    foo::<u32>();
    foo::<u64>();
}
```

Try it on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9488bc51594acd0a59de5d110b2768ea).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do more than just return a value, you could also match on the `TypeId` of your generic, but you'd have to wrap your return value in an enum because you can't return multiple types from a single `match` statement:

```rust
use std::any::TypeId;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value {
    u32(u32),
    u64(u64),
}

fn foo<T: 'static>() -> Value {
    match TypeId::of::<T>() {
        t if t == TypeId::of::<u32>() => {
            // other stuff
            Value::u32(0x01234567u32)
        },
        t if t == TypeId::of::<u64>() => {
            // other stuff
            Value::u64(0x0123456789abcdefu64)
        },
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo::<u32>());
    println!("{:?}", foo::<u64>());
}
```

The associated constants already mentioned are better if getting a constant value is the only functionality you need though.